# Active Admin Editor gem shows blank form like text area instead od editor (error0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, editor, admin, activeadmin

In active admin editor when i put ", as: :html_editor" it shows blank big form like text area instead of editor i have used github of ejholmes/active_admin_editor . please request you to provide solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you haven't included the required files, that is why it is just rendered as a text area rather than the editor. As per documentation, have you included this in your `application.css`?

```
//= require active_admin/editor/wysiwyg
```

Also, just a suggestion, this plugin is unmaintained since 2013. Better use [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/) and do the [integration](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/ckeditor-integration) with ActiveAdmin

Comment: I got the solution of it. One theme's javascript was overiding it.